# How to test my website most efficiently?

Tags: php, mysql, debugging

I have coded a big project using PHP and Mysql.

How can I test it and find errors most efficiently? Any tips? Or I need just to review code once more and test it on browser, that's it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient way to test any project is to test as you develop, not at the end.  Unit testing applies small tests to small modules as they are being written, so that you have a solid base on which to build.

Comment: Yeah, of course I was testing it when I was developing it. But still, I want to make sure it is as unbuggy as possible. Anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Like all other projects.

- Unit testing - test code. You can use [PHPUnit](http://phpunit.sourceforge.net/).
- UI testing - test user interface. You can use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).
- And finally maybe think about private beta and let users easily report bugs?

Answer (score 1):

if you do not have testing enviroment set up and running make sure that error_reporting(E_ALL); and have test users focus on break it instead for work with it...
And read logs...

I running under Zend Server what gives me more performance info and I stronglly recommended it for develop, test, and production stage

Answer (score 0):

You can test your page with the display_errors directive on (or by adding this at the beginning of your file "error_reporting(E_ALL);"
One of good way is also to have some beta testers. 
And some useful tools can help too, like the "web developper toolbar" addon.

Answer (score 0):

if you think that it's done and you've fixed all the bugs you can find, you can always recruit a group a testers to "do their worst" to the app. Have 10 or so people try out every part of it and really put some stress on it

Answer (score 0):

Try to go through this really very nice article on [UNIT](http://devzone.zend.com/article/2772) testing.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have mentioned, use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to show all the errors.

Use XAMPP and test it yourself.

Get multiple friends to come and try to make it break (always works for me).

Release it on a server you have - make sure everything works good.

Try to inject variables using any `$_REQUEST` variables you use. If you use them, see what happens when you change them to something incorrect or unexpected.

Try delete entries in your SQL table, see what that does.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of a learning curve, and some work for setup.  But you can create automated browser tests for all of your sites use cases.

http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/